# XSLT: removing elements with duplicate attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have xml and I want to remove elements (Elephant) that have duplicate child element (Cost) attribute values (dollars and cents are equal with sibling elements) and leave only one (Elephant) element.

Source xml (it's just a snippet of full document):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Day>      
         <Queue id="460402">
            <Time>4</Time>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="5" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="6" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="1" cents="46" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="55" cents="5" />
            </Elephant>
         </Queue>
         <Queue id="460404">
            <Time>3</Time>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="7" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="7" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="7" cents="2" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="7" cents="2" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="114" cents="5" />
            </Elephant>
         </Queue>
         <Queue id="4666047">
            <Time>7</Time>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
         </Queue>      
   </Day>
```

Expected outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Day>      
         <Queue id="460402">
            <Time>4</Time>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="5" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="6" />
            </Elephant>           
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="1" cents="46" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="55" cents="5" />
            </Elephant>
         </Queue>
         <Queue id="460404">
            <Time>3</Time>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="7" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="7" cents="2" />
            </Elephant>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="114" cents="5" />
            </Elephant>
         </Queue>
         <Queue id="4666047">
            <Time>7</Time>
            <Elephant>
               <Cost dollars="14" cents="1" />
            </Elephant>
         </Queue>      
   </Day>
```

I tried to run this xslt transformation but it is not working properly (more data are missing than it should be):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Elephant[Cost/@dollars= following-sibling:: Elephant/Cost/@dollars and Cost/@cents= following-sibling:: Elephant/Cost/@cents]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Queue">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Elephant)]|@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Elephant" group-by="Cost/(@dollars + 0.01 * @cents)">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```